# Calculating a field with a codeblock in gdal/ogr

Tags: python, gdalogr

I'm trying to calculate a field ('duplicates') to reflect the identical records, here's a part of the code:

```
d = []
def isDuplicate(t):
     import string
     global d
     iD = 0
     for item in d:
         if item == t:
             iD = 1
             continue
     if iD == 1:
         return 1
     elif iD == 0:
         d.append(t)
         return 0
```

I'm calling the function `isDuplicate()` in the code below:

```
ogrinfo input.shp -dialect SQLite -sql "UPDATE input SET duplicates = isDuplicate('account_No')"
```

It doesn't output anything and it doesn't give any errors either. Can anyone see the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isDuplicate()` is not an SQL function. OGR doesn't use python functions in SQL statements as far as I am aware. Not only that, as `ogrinfo` is a command line executable in a separate process, it won't even be aware that the python function exists.

You need to loop through each feature and use feature.SetField(field,value).

```
from osgeo import ogr

ds = ogr.Open(filepath, 1)
ogr.UseExceptions()

layer = ds.GetLayer()

values = set()
for feature in layer:
    value = feature.GetField("account_No")
    duplicate = int(value in values)
    feature.SetField('Duplicate', duplicate)
    layer.SetFeature(feature)
    values.add(value)

del layer, ds
```

Comment: Thank you @Luke. It works now. This works on shapefiles, how about FileGDB feature classes?

Comment: @Matt If your GDAL/OGR has the read/write "[Esri FileGDB driver](http://www.gdal.org/drv_filegdb.html)" compiled in (unlikely unless you compile GDAL/OGR yourself) or installed as a plugin, then yes it should work. It will not work with the read only GDAL/OGR "[OpenFileGDB](http://www.gdal.org/drv_openfilegdb.html)" driver that is compiled in by default (as of GDAL/OGR 1.11+).  Getting the ESRI FileGDB driver working in your GDAL/OGR installation is a whole new question... It's been asked a few times, so have a search of the site.